# Files.copy() при копировании теряет 5 байт. Чудеса

Tags: java, веб-программирование, websocket, файлы

Доброго всем времени суток. Появилась откуда ни возьмись проблемка, с которой я никогда ещё не сталкивался. Создал следующий веб-сервер:

```
class I2 implements Runnable {

    private ServerSocket i1;

    I2() throws Exception {
        this.i1 = new ServerSocket(80);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                new Thread(new i1(this.i1.accept())).start();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
            }
        }
    }

    private class i1 implements Runnable {

        Socket i1;
        OutputStream i2;

        i1(Socket i1) throws Exception {
            this.i1 = i1;
            this.i2 = this.i1.getOutputStream();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String i1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.i1.getInputStream())).readLine().split(" ")[1];
                if (!i1.startsWith(".")) {
                    if (i1.startsWith("/")) {
                        i1 = i1.substring(1, i1.length());
                    }
                    File i2 = new File(i1);
                    if (i2.exists()) {
                        Files.copy(i2.toPath(), this.i2);
                    }
                }
                this.i2.close();
                this.i1.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
            }
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

Если я конечно нормально оцениваю данный исходный код, то он должен отправлять запрашиваемый файл клиенту если он существует. Но. Мне удавалось открыть файл, который веб-сервер ещё не отправлял, однако не удавалось открыть файл, который веб-сервер мне прислал. Каким-то образом не получилось выполнить, так сказать, операцию по получению файла. Как видно на скриншоте

[image: скриншот отправленного и принятого файлов]

размер принятого файла меньше на 5 байт, однако размер файла на диске сохранился. Как это??? Что это за чудеса? Как исправить ошибку, помогите. Не знаю как конкретизировать проблему, поэтому интернет не дал мне ответа на мой вопрос.

Comment: ради интереса, попробуйте библиотеку FileUtils., если не сложно

Comment: Попробуйте добавить ожидание перед закрытием.  `this.i2.close(); this.i1.close();`

Comment: Пробовал. Безрезультатно. Даже пытался после Files.copy() сделать this.i2.flush() сделать, и даже деревенским способом через FileInputStream().read() в байты, а затем их в сокет. Проблема не в том, что мне просто не нравится, что размер файла меняется, а самое главное - файл повреждён.

Comment: Ещё вопрос - `while (true) {
            try {
                new Thread(new i1(this.i1.accept())).start();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
            }
        }`
разве корректная запись? не создаётся ли там куча тредов? что будет если убрать цикл - программа отработает 1 раз корректно или нет?

Comment: На диске файл занимает место, кратное размеру кластера файловой системы. Поэтому размер на диске остался прежним.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Браузер веб-клиента подозревает, что я, поначалу, должен отправить заголовки:

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK
>
> Content-Length: 80
>
> ...

и перед тем, как принять файл должно быть два символа `System.lineSeparator()` (ну или, если проще выразится `/n`), что означает, что должно быть две пустые строки. Они то и весят те самые 5 байт.

Вообще, я в этом разобрался открыв этот бинарный файл в блокноте и посмотрел, с каких закорючек начинается и заканчивается повреждённый файл, в отличие от корректного; и понял, что несколько закорючек в начале повреждённого файла отсутствовали. Тут то я и решил проблему простым деревенским способом, заменив некоторый исходный код на следующий:

```
...
this.i2.write(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0});
this.i2.flush();
Files.copy(i2.toPath(), this.i2);
...
```

Comment: Заголовки эти мне нафиг не нужны, поэтому браузер веб-клиента устанавливает их по умолчанию, и думает, что после двух пустых строк закончились заголовки, а следовательно, дальше скачивается содержимое того, или иного файла.

Comment: Когда я вижу "закорючки в начале файла" то сразу думаю о [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Маркер_последовательности_байтов). Однако, это касается только текстовых файлов.